# How to show a text when hovering?

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

I have a footer in which I have different icons for my social media. Now, I want to create a hover effect, which displays the name of hovered icons.

For example: My mouse is over the facebook icon, and then the text 'Facebook' should come up in a div, located in a div below!

I know how to create this, however, I don't know how I display these names in the same div at the exact same place. How can I do this?

```
<div id="footer1" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="ft-div-left"> </div>
      <div class="ft-div-right">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="ft-div-middle">
        <center>
          <p>
            <center>
              <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;"><span class="" style="color: white;"></span></a> 
              <a href=""  style="text-decoration:none; color:white;"><span class="" style="color: white;"></span></a> 
              <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;"><span class="icon-stumbleupon3" id="issuu" style="color: white;"></span></a> 
              <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;"><span class ="icon-twitter3"></span></a>
              </br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <span style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:grey;">&copy; 2014. All Rights Reserved.</span>
            </center>
          </p>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div id="hoverText">
         <span>Here goes the text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does the Tooltip functionality provide you with what you need?

Comment: I have been thinking about that for a long time, but this is not how I want it to work! Did u understand what I mean?

Comment: I think I get what you mean... A Tooltip would most likely show the text somewhere over the image (in a non-specific place), whereas what you want is the text to appear in a specified position just below each image. Correct?

Comment: Does something like this reflect what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/BC4eY/1581/

Comment: try adding a mouse-over handler to your <a ...>: onmouseover="document.getElementById('hoverText').innerHTML("Facebook")

Comment: I'm quickly gonna try this!

Comment: if @Stu1986C solution doesn't work try one of these: I am using this on a website currently: http://jquerytools.org/demos/ and you've got this too: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Can I write text with jquery?

Comment: As per @CodeBird's recommendation, the JQueryUI Tooltip is worth a shot. I've used it before and is pretty reliable as to where it is positioned :)

Comment: @fjw, Yes you can write text with JQuery but I tend to prefer to keep things uncoupled: ie. My jquery does all the work, my HTML is for the textual display and my CSS changes the way in which stuff looks :)

Comment: @Stu1986C, the problems is that I want multiple names to display as Twitter, FB, Stumbleupon etc. How can I solve this? I'm not into jqurey unfortunatley

Comment: @fjw check the demos and source code, it is easy to apply if you have basic understanding of javascript. you just have to load the jquery and add title="facebook", title="twitter" etc... for your images.

Answer (score 18):

I personally use the `title=""` tooltip inside whatever tag I am using.

```
<div id="hoverText">
     <span title="hover text">Here goes the text</span>
</div>
```

This `title=""` tooltip seem to work about anywhere and on anything.

Comment: Thanks Léla, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a CSS only answer was what you are looking for. 
You can do this with CSS using  `visibility` and ofcourse `:hover`

Here's the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5P2Fh/)

Example:

Html-

```
            <div id="facebookicon">
                <img src="https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/assets/asset.f.logo.lg.png"> </img>
                </div>
            <div id="onhoverfb">Follow Us</div>
```

CSS -

```
            #onhoverfb{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            #facebookicon:hover ~ #onhoverfb{
                visibility: visible;
            }
```

Remember to set the `:hover` on the div that is going to be hovered over.

Extra: You can always add the css `transition` property to have the hover appear more smoothly. Like a fade in.